# Sort given order with xslt sort

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm using

```
<xsl:sort />
```

to sort the rows in a table. The value of

```
@result
```

can be Failed, Ignored or Passed. As it is sorted alphabetically it will not come out in the order I want. Which is

Failed -
Ignored -
Passed

How do I achieve this I am using xslt 1.0

This is my code

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="results/test-case">
<xsl:sort select="@result" /> 
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: can you provide xml sample ?

Comment: include the XML too..

Comment: You say you want Failed, Ignored, Passed - that _is_ alphabetical order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your question the ordering you've asked for is consistent with alphabetical order, so a plain `<xsl:sort select="@result" />` should work correctly.  But in cases where a non-alphabetic fixed ordering is required I tend to use the following trick.

First define the order in a variable, with entries delimited by some character that is not part of any of the options:

```
<xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="'|Passed|Failed|Ignored|'" />
```

Then use

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="string-length(
    substring-before($sortOrder, concat('|', @result, '|')))" />
```

The trick here is that `substring-before($sortOrder, concat('|', @result, '|'))` will be the empty string when `@result` is Passed, the string `"|Passed"` when `@result` is Failed, and the string `"|Passed|Failed"` when `@result` is Ignored.  Thus sorting numerically by the *length* of these strings will produce the ordering given by `$sortOrder`.

In this particular case you don't even need the `concat`, just

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="string-length(
    substring-before($sortOrder, @result))" />
```

will do the job.  The `concat` is there in the general case to handle situations where one item in the ordering is a substring of another. For example, for an ordering of `'|Passed|Pass|Failed|Fail|'` the concat is required otherwise "Pass" would be treated the same as "Passed" rather than being consistently sorted after it.

Comment: It's great to search stack overflow and find answers like this.

Answer (score 2):

The following alternate XSLT is definitely not as cool as @IanRoberts's but it may be helpful in some setups when e.g. the sorting order is defined by another process and hence be available in another XML file.

The following file `sort.xml` is a simple example defining a sort order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sort_indices>
  <sort_index name="my_sort">
    <entry key="Failed" index="2"/>
    <entry key="Ignored" index="0"/>
    <entry key="Passed" index="1"/>
  </sort_index>
</sort_indices>
```

This file can be sourced into the XSLT using `document` and then used as sorting index:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="sort_index" select="document('sort.xml')/sort_indices/sort_index[@name='my_sort']"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <test-cases>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="results/test-case">
        <xsl:sort select="$sort_index/entry[@key = current()/@result]/@index"/> 
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </test-cases>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way the sorting uses the numeric index values of the sort index directly without having to derive them from the length of an encoded string. It looks cleaner but as I said it's not as cool. :-)

Comment: Nice idea.  It would be even nicer in XSLT 2.0 where you could define a key over the `sort_index` to do direct lookups from the entry key to index, but that would rely on the three-argument form of the `key` function so not possible in 1.0.

Comment: That's actually what I tried first but I had to learn that it's not possible to use the sub tree returned by `document` as context in the `match` attribute of `<key>`. :-)

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 the `key` function always looks up nodes in the document that the current context node belongs to.  Therefore it _is_ possible to look up nodes in another document but only by switching the context (e.g. with `<xsl:for-each select="$sort_index">`).  But in an `xsl:sort` expression the context is always the thing you're trying to sort.  XSLT 2.0 adds a third parameter to `key` that lets you look things up in a subtree rooted at an arbitrary node, which could belong to a document other than the current context one.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 2.0 has a more elegant way:

```
<xsl:sort select="index-of(('Passed', 'Failed', 'Ignored'), .) "/>
```

Comment: But this question is tagged as `xslt-1.0`.

Comment: So?  The question was asked 7 years ago, and the XSLT 2.0 solution is more relevant today than it was in 2013.  The original asker clearly doesn't need this input.  This question and answer comes up in Google today.  I could not find a 2.0 answer, eventually came up with this elegant solution.  So posted it here to help other people in 2020 and later.  I find most older questions with 1.0 solutions have 2.0 (and 3.0) answer added years later, and I always find that helpful.

Comment: *"I could not find a 2.0 answer"* You need better search methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32625442/3016153