# XSLT: Incremental variable and parameter assigning

Tags: variables, xslt

---

Hi

i need the below xml

```
<Data>
    <Employees>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeName>Ram</EmployeeName>
            <EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeName>Helen</EmployeeName>
            <EmployeeID>432</EmployeeID>
            <Gender>F</Gender>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeName>Dinesh</EmployeeName>
            <EmployeeID>321</EmployeeID>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
</Data>
```

converting to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee Gender="Male" Current="true" index="1">
        <Name>Ram</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Gender="Male" Current="false" index="2">
        <Name>Dinesh</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Gender="Female" Current="false" index="3">
        <Name>Helen</Name>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

The stylesheet i have used is as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Employees>

                <xsl:for-each select="Employees/Employee[Gender = 'M']">
                <Employee Gender="Male">
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeName"/>
                    </Name>
                                </Employee>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="Employees/Employee[Gender = 'F']">
                <Employee Gender="Female">
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeName"/>
                    </Name>
                                </Employee>
                </xsl:for-each>


        </Employees>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried using several sample such as  but nothings seems to work out. Can any one help me out in this please? This is just a sample code i have put together to explain the problem.

Or to be more specific,

"Current" is required to be set in the first employee node only. The index on the other hand should be on all the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position()` to determine the element's position under its parent. I would also tend to refactor the template in favour of `apply-templates` and to DRY up the repeated Employee mapping for male and female.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="Data">
      <Employees>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Employees/Employee">
            <xsl:sort select="Gender" order="descending" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </Employees>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Employee">
      <xsl:variable name="gender">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Gender='M'">Male</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Gender='F'">Female</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Unknown</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="current">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">true</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <Employee Gender="{$gender}" Current="{$current}" index="{position()}">
            <Name>
               <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeName"/>
            </Name>
         </Employee>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Edit* As per @Ians solution, I've added the sorting and `Current` attribute. I'm not really sure what the complication is, however - perhaps I've missed something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a single `for-each` (or more likely `apply-templates` but I'll follow your current structure) so you can use `position()` to generate the indexes.  In order to put all the `Male` employees first followed by the `Female` ones it's sufficient to `<xsl:sort>` the `for-each` in descending order of `Gender` (because "M" is later in the alphabet than "F"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Employees>
            <xsl:for-each select="Employees/Employee">
                <xsl:sort select="Gender" order="descending" />
                <Employee Gender="{Gender}" index="{position()}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="Current">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">true</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeName"/>
                    </Name>
                </Employee>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Employees>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks so much for the quick reply. But as I have mentioned this is a sample. But in the real problem, I cannot sort it out and i require them in certain order. So two for-each seems essential. The example you have given restarts indexing again for the female node. If there is a way to go through the xml after the transformation and the index it it would be good.

Comment: @user2969793 no, the example I've given will produce one continuous sequence of numbers, it won't restart numbering with the female nodes.  If you need a specific (non-alphabetic) fixed ordering then you can use [the trick I describe in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19788136/592139) to do it in a single pass.