# Sort XML elements in predetermined order using XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have to following XML:

```
 <root>
       <a></a>
       <b></b>
       <a></a>
       <a></a>
       <b></b>
       <c></c>
</root>
```

The order of a, b and c elements is random.
Now I want to sort the elements in a predefined way (first b, then a, then c).

I tried the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
         <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which sorts the element by name, thus a,b,c as expected.

Is there a way to define the order of the sort other then descending/ascending?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I want to sort the elements in a predefined way (first b, then a,
>   then c).

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="b"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="c"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's another:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
            <xsl:sort select="index-of(('b', 'a', 'c'), name())" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you could try to do something fancy, like `translate(name(), 'b', '!')`, which will put `<b>` before `<a>`. Of course, it orders *any* "b" in the string before "a".

Comment: And the common way in XSLT 2.0 is to use collations. You could define a collation that creates any order, provided your processor supports creating user-defined collations.

Comment: @Abel I suspect "a", "b" and "c" are just an example, and the real names are different. Constructing a collation to re-arrange three specific **words** seems impractical. That's also why translate() would not work (at least not easily). In XSLT 1.0, you could use (roughly)  `string-length(substring-before('bac', name()))`.

Comment: If indeed the order is on _words_, as opposed to the sorting order of individual characters, it gets tricky in XSLT 1.0. Though if it just a few words, you can add several `xsl:sort` elements together. Each of them can have an ascending/descending.

Comment: @Abel "*Though if it just a few words, you can add several `xsl:sort` elements together.*" Or several `xsl:apply-templates` elements together...

Comment: The apply-templates select was the solution I went with. Thank you for your help.