# can we customize the order of tables in an xml? i.e parent nodes? not child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML and would like to know one thing. I know that we can order the content of xml using xsl:sort.But, I really wonder is there any way to re-order the parent nodes in xml (my xml has 9 different parent nodes and hundreds of child nodes in each). My xml looks like this:

```
 <upcase>
   <A>
   ...
   </A>
   <C>
   ...
  </C>
   <F>
    ....</F>
   <B>
    ..
   </B>
 </upcase>
```

I wish to customize the order like C B F A which means i would like to know the xsl template for this

```
   <upcase>
    <C>
     ...
     </C>
     <B>
      ...
      </B>
      <F>
    ....</F>
     <A>
       ..
     </A>
   </upcase>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624886/sort-xml-elements-in-predetermined-order-using-xslt/32625442#32625442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a fixed number of these nodes the simplest way is to do

```
<xsl:template match="upcase">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="C, B, F, A"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or in XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:template match="upcase">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="C"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="B"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="F"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="A"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```