# XSLT sorting case sensitive

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <Title>Empire Burlesque</Title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <cOuntry>USA</cOuntry>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I want to order the elements within "cd" element by their names, not by content, and I want the ordering to be case sensitive, uppercase first. I have tried the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()" case-order="upper-first" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would expect to get the following result where "Title" comes first because of the uppercase T and where "cOuntry" comes before "company".

```
<catalog>
   <cd>
      <Title>Empire Burlesque</Title>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <cOuntry>USA</cOuntry>
      <company>Columbia</company>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <year>1985</year>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

But I get the following result:

```
<catalog>
   <cd>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <company>Columbia</company>
      <cOuntry>USA</cOuntry>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <Title>Empire Burlesque</Title>
      <year>1985</year>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

According to http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6461.html#d9252e1397 "case is only considered if the two strings (as a whole) are the same except in case".

I want case to be considered first. How do I sort it really case sensitive?

Test online at: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5DG

Answer (score 1):

Your online tool uses an XSLT 2.0 processor, Saxon 9, assuming XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="name()" collation="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and get the order

```
<catalog>
   <cd>
      <Title>Empire Burlesque</Title>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <cOuntry>USA</cOuntry>
      <company>Columbia</company>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <year>1985</year>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Yes, sure works with that online tool, but I'm afraid it does not work with the Java 7 processor I am using.

Comment: With a Java application you can also use Saxon 9, it is available on Maven or from Sourceforge or from saxonica.com. If you put it on the class path and use the JAXP transformations APIs, you have XSLT 2.0 support without needing any change to your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

This hack will work for your example, but I am not sure how generic it truly is:

```
<xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '00000000000000000000000000')" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added:

Here's a more refined version - though it may still produce unexpected results if the input contains any of the replacement characters:

```
<xsl:sort select="translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '!?~()[]@$*\#%+=|0123456789')" />
```

Note that this is custom-tailored for the Xalan processor.

---

**Update**:
For a more elaborate version, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172911/3016153

Comment: Sir, <xsl:sort select="translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" /> is this also ok? Please suggest.

Comment: @RudramuniTP That won't accomplish anything, because the Xalan processor already treats upper-case characters as equal to their lower-case counterparts, when sorting. That's exactly the problem OP is trying to avoid. Ideally, there would be a `lang` setting that would override this behavior, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for u r suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution from here: [Sort given order with xslt sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787773/sort-given-order-with-xslt-sort)

```
<xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="'|Title|artist|cOuntry|company|price|year|'" />
<xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" 
                select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder, concat('|', name(), '|')))" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You did not tell us the element names were known in advance. In such case, you could apply templates individually to each in turn, and skip the sorting altogether.