# <xls:sort is not working when special character [i.e. dot(.), colon(:), semicolon(;)] is present

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, dom4j

**xsl:sort** is not working properly when special character like ", : ;" are presents. What might be the problem here?

I am trying to render html from xml data with **java dom4j library**. Though the real project has multiple sorting criteria, I am illustrating a summery here to the specific problem.

**The expected sorting order is ASCIIbatical order.** The online [String Sort Toll](https://onlinestringtools.com/sort-strings) is also giving my expected output.

I have some xml data ex:

```
<employee>
    <name>
        <![CDATA[test 1.8 - test]]>
    </name>
    <name>
        <![CDATA[test 4 - test]]>
    </name>
    <name>
        <![CDATA[Test 2 - test]]>
    </name>
</employee>
```

I am trying to sort them with xsl transformer with . The snippet for sorting it...

```
<xsl:for-each select="employee/name">
    <xsl:sort select="name" case-order="upper-first"/>
...
```

Expected **Output Order**:

```
Test 2 - test
test 1.8 - test
test 4 - test
```

The **Output Order** I am getting:

```
test 1.8 - test
Test 2 - test
test 4 - test
```

Like this getting the order

```
; - ;
& - &
T1 - T1
```

In stead of

```
& - &
; - ;
T1 - T1
```

Comment: Please provide a clear statement of the logic by which you want to sort the items.

Comment: Many people would consider the order you are getting is entirely reasonable, e.g. for the index of a book. It's not clear what exactly are the rules you want to apply. The actual sort rules depend on the XSLT processor you are using. If you want precise control over the sort order, especially in XSLT 1.0, then it's probablly simplest to do a preprocessing transformation phase that computes a sort key, for example by stripping out ignorable characters and converting letters to upper case or lower case.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear statement. I want the sorting in "ASCIIbetical" order, character gets priority following the ASCII table, [Uppercase < Lowercase]  [& < ;] and characters are not ignorable, all special character should consider @Michael Kay

Answer (score 0):

First, your code snippet sorts `employee`s, not `name`s.

Now, the result you get **is** the expected output after sorting the names. If you want the entry of `Test 2 - test` to come first because it starts with a capital `T`, then you need to do:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:sort collation="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint"/>
        ....
    </xsl:for-each>
```

and you will need a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 or higher for that.

I don't see what the presence of the dot or any other character has to do with any of this.

Comment: Problem is, I am working in a legacy code and I could not change the XSLT version to 2.0 . 
Another thing, I am a bit confused that the problem may not be only with the Capital Case it also among the Special Characters (I have added new example on the last)

Comment: I am afraid your options in XSLT 1.0 are rather limited. For an example of case-sensitive sorting, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38973853/3016153. But do note the caveats stated there.

Answer (score 0):

> **The expected sorting order is ASCIIbatical order.**

If we accept the definition of "sorting in ASCIIbetical order" as sorting by the order in which characters appear in the ASCII table (i.e. their Unicode codepoint values), while considering only printable characters (i.e. characters in the range from `&#32;` to  `&#126;`), then we could do the sorting as shown in the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>
   <char ascii="32"> </char>
   <char ascii="45">-</char>
   <char ascii="95">_</char>
   <char ascii="44">,</char>
   <char ascii="59">;</char>
   <char ascii="58">:</char>
   <char ascii="33">!</char>
   <char ascii="63">?</char>
   <char ascii="47">/</char>
   <char ascii="46">.</char>
   <char ascii="96">`</char>
   <char ascii="94">^</char>
   <char ascii="126">~</char>
   <char ascii="39">'</char>
   <char ascii="34">"</char>
   <char ascii="40">(</char>
   <char ascii="41">)</char>
   <char ascii="91">[</char>
   <char ascii="93">]</char>
   <char ascii="123">{</char>
   <char ascii="125">}</char>
   <char ascii="64">@</char>
   <char ascii="36">$</char>
   <char ascii="42">*</char>
   <char ascii="92">\</char>
   <char ascii="38">&amp;</char>
   <char ascii="35">#</char>
   <char ascii="37">%</char>
   <char ascii="43">+</char>
   <char ascii="60">&lt;</char>
   <char ascii="61">=</char>
   <char ascii="62">&gt;</char>
   <char ascii="124">|</char>
   <char ascii="48">0</char>
   <char ascii="49">1</char>
   <char ascii="50">2</char>
   <char ascii="51">3</char>
   <char ascii="52">4</char>
   <char ascii="53">5</char>
   <char ascii="54">6</char>
   <char ascii="55">7</char>
   <char ascii="56">8</char>
   <char ascii="57">9</char>
   <char ascii="97">a</char>
   <char ascii="65">A</char>
   <char ascii="98">b</char>
   <char ascii="66">B</char>
   <char ascii="99">c</char>
   <char ascii="67">C</char>
   <char ascii="100">d</char>
   <char ascii="68">D</char>
   <char ascii="101">e</char>
   <char ascii="69">E</char>
   <char ascii="102">f</char>
   <char ascii="70">F</char>
   <char ascii="103">g</char>
   <char ascii="71">G</char>
   <char ascii="104">h</char>
   <char ascii="72">H</char>
   <char ascii="105">i</char>
   <char ascii="73">I</char>
   <char ascii="106">j</char>
   <char ascii="74">J</char>
   <char ascii="107">k</char>
   <char ascii="75">K</char>
   <char ascii="108">l</char>
   <char ascii="76">L</char>
   <char ascii="109">m</char>
   <char ascii="77">M</char>
   <char ascii="110">n</char>
   <char ascii="78">N</char>
   <char ascii="111">o</char>
   <char ascii="79">O</char>
   <char ascii="112">p</char>
   <char ascii="80">P</char>
   <char ascii="113">q</char>
   <char ascii="81">Q</char>
   <char ascii="114">r</char>
   <char ascii="82">R</char>
   <char ascii="115">s</char>
   <char ascii="83">S</char>
   <char ascii="116">t</char>
   <char ascii="84">T</char>
   <char ascii="117">u</char>
   <char ascii="85">U</char>
   <char ascii="118">v</char>
   <char ascii="86">V</char>
   <char ascii="119">w</char>
   <char ascii="87">W</char>
   <char ascii="120">x</char>
   <char ascii="88">X</char>
   <char ascii="121">y</char>
   <char ascii="89">Y</char>
   <char ascii="122">z</char>
   <char ascii="90">Z</char>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="ascii">!"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="en">-_,;:!?/.`^~'"()[]{}@$*\&amp;#%+&lt;=>|0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="char">
            <xsl:sort select="translate(., $ascii, $en)" lang="en"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
<char ascii="32"> </char>
<char ascii="33">!</char>
<char ascii="34">"</char>
<char ascii="35">#</char>
<char ascii="36">$</char>
<char ascii="37">%</char>
<char ascii="38">&amp;</char>
<char ascii="39">'</char>
<char ascii="40">(</char>
<char ascii="41">)</char>
<char ascii="42">*</char>
<char ascii="43">+</char>
<char ascii="44">,</char>
<char ascii="45">-</char>
<char ascii="46">.</char>
<char ascii="47">/</char>
<char ascii="48">0</char>
<char ascii="49">1</char>
<char ascii="50">2</char>
<char ascii="51">3</char>
<char ascii="52">4</char>
<char ascii="53">5</char>
<char ascii="54">6</char>
<char ascii="55">7</char>
<char ascii="56">8</char>
<char ascii="57">9</char>
<char ascii="58">:</char>
<char ascii="59">;</char>
<char ascii="60">&lt;</char>
<char ascii="61">=</char>
<char ascii="62">&gt;</char>
<char ascii="63">?</char>
<char ascii="64">@</char>
<char ascii="65">A</char>
<char ascii="66">B</char>
<char ascii="67">C</char>
<char ascii="68">D</char>
<char ascii="69">E</char>
<char ascii="70">F</char>
<char ascii="71">G</char>
<char ascii="72">H</char>
<char ascii="73">I</char>
<char ascii="74">J</char>
<char ascii="75">K</char>
<char ascii="76">L</char>
<char ascii="77">M</char>
<char ascii="78">N</char>
<char ascii="79">O</char>
<char ascii="80">P</char>
<char ascii="81">Q</char>
<char ascii="82">R</char>
<char ascii="83">S</char>
<char ascii="84">T</char>
<char ascii="85">U</char>
<char ascii="86">V</char>
<char ascii="87">W</char>
<char ascii="88">X</char>
<char ascii="89">Y</char>
<char ascii="90">Z</char>
<char ascii="91">[</char>
<char ascii="92">\</char>
<char ascii="93">]</char>
<char ascii="94">^</char>
<char ascii="95">_</char>
<char ascii="96">`</char>
<char ascii="97">a</char>
<char ascii="98">b</char>
<char ascii="99">c</char>
<char ascii="100">d</char>
<char ascii="101">e</char>
<char ascii="102">f</char>
<char ascii="103">g</char>
<char ascii="104">h</char>
<char ascii="105">i</char>
<char ascii="106">j</char>
<char ascii="107">k</char>
<char ascii="108">l</char>
<char ascii="109">m</char>
<char ascii="110">n</char>
<char ascii="111">o</char>
<char ascii="112">p</char>
<char ascii="113">q</char>
<char ascii="114">r</char>
<char ascii="115">s</char>
<char ascii="116">t</char>
<char ascii="117">u</char>
<char ascii="118">v</char>
<char ascii="119">w</char>
<char ascii="120">x</char>
<char ascii="121">y</char>
<char ascii="122">z</char>
<char ascii="123">{</char>
<char ascii="124">|</char>
<char ascii="125">}</char>
<char ascii="126">~</char>
</root>
```

### (*)IMPORTANT:

The above result was produced using the Xalan 2.7.2 processor with `lang="en"`. You may easily get a different result if using a different processor and/or a different `lang` value. In such case you need to adjust the `$en` parameter to reflect the actual sorting order of your environment.

And of course, as shown in my other answer, all this is unnecessary if you are using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

This might not fit your requirement at all, but noting that DOM4J uses "live" lists for element content, sorting the nodes directly in code becomes quite elegant:

```
doc.getRootElement().content().sort(Comparator.comparing(Node::getText));
```

Of course it messes up any existing formatting, but that can probably be fixed with a pretty printing option.